# Subscripts in xlabels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following commands

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + geom_boxplot()
```

produce this graph.

[image: this graph]. I wonder how to get xlabels as ctrl, trt_1 and trt_2, here 1 and 2 are in subscripts. As I need to have the graphs in png format so I'm avoiding tikzDevice and pgfSweave. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: does this do what you want? `levels(PlantGrowth$group)[2:3] <- c("trt\n1", "trt\n2")
`

Comment: Thanks @Chase for your comment. Your suggestion adds new line but I need something like this $trt_1$. Any suggestion.

Comment: doh - I wasn't smart enough to realize what you meant by subscript the first time around...looks like kohske got you going with `expression()`. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is an example:

```
ggplot(PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = unique(PlantGrowth$group), labels = c(expression(ctrl), expression(trt[1]), expression(trt[2])))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kohske. You are `ggplot2` wizard

Comment: `breaks = levels(PlantGrowth$group)` seems more appropriate. What do you think?

Comment: I wonder how to get the same kind of subscripts in legend. Thanks